# Merged Resource Dictionaries of Windows does not reflect on child controls

Tags: c#, wpf, hierarchy, resourcedictionary

Resource dictionary merged to the Window as given in the code below.

```
<Window.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="DefaultTheme.xaml"/>
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Window.Resources>
```

I had created a custom control for context menu and had created the corresponding style in the DefaultTheme.xaml file. Even though at the window level it had the resource dictionary merged, the styles were not accessible for the custom controls.

Since it was custom control I had to merge the dictionary in the C# constructor like this -

```
const string defaultThemePath = "DefaultTheme.xaml";
var dictionary = new ResourceDictionary { Source = new Uri(defaultThemePath, UriKind.Relative) };
Resources.MergedDictionaries.Add(dictionary);
```

If the resource dictionary is merged, it should be available for child controls is an expectation. Is my understanding wrong about merged resource dictionary?

**Edit**

As @Rohit Vats has rightly pointed, my custom control is context menu and it is not part of the visual child of the window. Hence it does not have the resource dictionary inherited.

Comment: It will be accessible as long as custom control is visual child of window. If that's not the case, merge dictionaries under App resources.

Comment: Thanks Rohit. The custom control is a context menu. If I am right it is not a visual child of window :)... So how should I merge dictionary so that even context menu can have the styles... Instantiating in the constructor looks dirty to me.

Comment: I have added an answer to your query (couldn't add here since it needs more space to explain).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just quickly check by putting one `SolidColorBrush` in random ResourceDictionary and merge it under App resources and use that resource from ContextMenu and ContextMenu was able to access the resource.

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms750613%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), StaticResource lookup behaviour works like this:

> 1. The lookup process checks for the requested key within the resource
>      dictionary defined by the element that sets the property.
> 2. The lookup process then traverses the logical tree upward, to the
>      parent element and its resource dictionary. This continues until the
>      root element is reached.
> 3. Next, **application resources are checked**. Application resources are
>      those resources within the resource dictionary that is defined by the
>      Application object for your WPF application.

As evident from the above assertion, **it looks for logical parent and not Visual parent and in case resource is not found anywhere, it looks for resource under App resources**.

So, your case for ContextMenu will work if you merge resources under App resources.

Comment: I don't want to do that either, i.e. merge to the app resource. I will try to use a static accessor for the resource dictionary rather than hardcoding the name. Accepting the answer for the clarification

Comment: Why you don't want to merge under App resources? You are already merging it under Window resources anyhow.

Comment: Because my changes are at user control level. The integrated app is not yet done and it might change how the resources are loaded. So don't want to create a dependency for my module when things change at app level.

Comment: Is it good to merge the same dictionary multiple times? once at the user control level and once more at the window/app level?

Comment: Yeah you can merge that. That's valid scenario in many cases like you want to use resource in different RD's for that you have to merge seperately.